# Isometric Camera Movement in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm still rather new to unity and I'm trying to figure out how to setup an isometric camera controller that's not bound to a rigidbody. Below is the isometric character controller code that uses a rigidbody. However I would like to make camera that moves in a similar way but doesn't use rigidbody. I've tried setting the rigidbody to a separate layer to prevent collisions but it feels like an inelegant solution.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Rigidbody rb;
    [SerializeField] float moveSpeed = 5;
    Vector3 input;

    void Update() {
        GatherInput();
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        Move();
    }

    void GatherInput() {
        input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
    }

    void Move() {
        rb.MovePosition(transform.position + input.ToIso() * input.normalized.magnitude * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}

public static class Helpers 
{
    static Matrix4x4 isoMatrix = Matrix4x4.Rotate(Quaternion.Euler(0, 45, 0));
    public static Vector3 ToIso(this Vector3 input) => isoMatrix.MultiplyPoint3x4(input);
}
```

The code still works for moving the camera, however because of the rigidbody, it collides with the other GameObjects in the Scene. Setting it on a different layer solves this problem, but it feels like an inelegant solution and I want to learn the proper way to setup an isometric camera controller.

Comment: Have you tried assigning a new position to `transform.position` rather than calling `rb.MovePosition`? At first glance that might work, or there might be some issue that I'm missing.